# Getting List Type from a List with a declared type of the superclass

Tags: c#, reflection

I have three classes (Animal, Mammal, and Reptile) where Mammal and Reptile are subclasses of Animal.

I have a list of Animals that I populate with only Mammals or only Reptiles. I want to get the type inside the list at run-time.

Using the list itself does not work.

```
Type type = myList.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
// type -> Animal

Type type = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
// type -> Animal
```

This list is also a property of another class, let's call it Biome. Biome has two properties, Reptiles (List) and Mammals(List). Given an instance the collection property, can I find the item type?

Comment: could you show your list definition as well?  Looks like you are doing List<T>

Comment: Can you please give complete code samples showing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, including all the data types involed?  You can strip them down and fake your types, as long as it shows what you're trying to accomplish.  With the way you've asked the question, I can't tell either a) what element types are involved, or b) what list type you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Get the type of an item in the list, not the type of the list:

```
Type type = myList[0].GetType();
```

Comment: This can work sometimes, but depends on the OP needs to do with the type.  This will only work if the list isn't empty.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Yes, this assumes that there is at least one item in the list. If there aren't any items in the list, the items in the list doesn't have any type at all.

Comment: If it is an `ArrayList` (.Net 1.1) this is true.  If it is a `List<T>`, then it has an element type.  But he's talking about super classes, so maybe you are correct.  The way the question is asked is confusing...

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: The list has the element type `Animal`, which is the base class for the items in the list, the op wants the actual type of the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0 and **know the type of element when you create the list** you can apply [Generic Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) as follows:

```
List<Animal> myList = new List<Reptile>();
```

That would generate the appropriate output using Reflection.

Comment: No, you can't. Variance can't be applied to concrete types like `List<T>`, even in C#4.